# How to make FFmpeg use output codec and pix_fmt same with input

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a batch process shell script resizing videos, that are of unpredictable codecs and containers.
I expected that the resized video should be mostly the same with the original one except image sizes. Which means that a video with png codec in a mov container should output with png codec not h264.

But I realized that only keeping the extension names the same are not enough. FFmpeg tends to use default encoder associated with the extension name rather than trying to keep the same with the input.

**Is there any *magical* parameter that will tell FFmpeg to try to use input codec instead of guessing by output file name?**

Running FFmpeg twice to get information in advance would be my last choice, because it will make my script a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Get the codecs with `ffprobe`, and then specify them on the `ffmpeg` command, pseudocode is something like:

```
output = parse_json( `ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json output.mp4` )
stream_args = ""
for stream in output['streams']:
    stream_args += " -codec:0:" + stream['index'] + " " + stream['codec_name']

ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 " + stream_args + " output.mp4
```